# Get a value from decoded query string

Tags: c#

I have an encoded query string and have decoded it using the function `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(urlEncodedQueryString)`. It decodes fine and I get the result as:

```
pagesize=5&morekey=morekey&last_updated=2018-11-30 10:06:09.203&queryfilter=filter
```

How can I get the value of the `last_updated` decoded query string (i.e 2018-11-30 10:06:09.203) so that I can parse it to a `DateTime` and use it for my further implementation?

I tried with this code but it only returns null.

```
string decodedQueryString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(urlEncodedQueryString);
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(decodedQueryString);

lastUpdatedDateUtc = DateTime.Parse(parameters["last_updated="]);
```

I want the `lastUpdatedDateUtc` values as `2018-11-30 10:06:09.203`

Comment: Your code looks fine other than having a superfluous `=` when accessing `parameters`. (Although I do wonder if you need to do URL decoding yourself. You should definitely seek to avoid double-decoding that which was encoded once and I think `ParseQueryString` does decoding itself)

Comment: Remove the `=` from `"last_updated="`, you should have the third line as `DateTime.Parse(parameters["last_updated"]); ` not `DateTime.Parse(parameters["last_updated="]);`. If that is a type then your code looks fine.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why exactly do you have a url encoded querystring? I mean, it makes sense to encode individual parts of the querystring, but it is odd to encode **the entire thing**.

Comment: This encoded query is string is what we get from one our client Web API and now we are creating windows service to decod it and use those values individually. If encoding the whole query string sounds stupid that is nothing we can help it . That is what the requirement is and we can't argue about it with them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
lastUpdatedDateUtc = DateTime.Parse(parameters["last_updated="]);
```

to

```
lastUpdatedDateUtc = DateTime.Parse(parameters["last_updated"]);
```

The = isn't supposed to be in the parameter name

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions. They have no use.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I didn't know that was a thing, I'll keep it in mind

Comment: That was not a typo I didn't know how to get the value, so I tried in different ways and tested it by unit test but nothing worked. I just pasted one of the way I tried